# Usecase of Task.Run() in async operations

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I've been looking for some information about this topic as right now I'm kind of confused about the problems and benefits of using this approach inside an async API.

I'm developing an API with OCR methods which consume quite a bit of resources and take some time to end the processing.

Right now I'm using the following approach to perform a petition where I'm sending a ticket image and returning an object with all the information related to it. As you can see, I'm using `Task.Run()` to perform the OCR processing and therefore make the call async

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetTicketData([FromBody] PostTicketRequest ticket)
{
    try
    {
        using (var Extractor = new TicketExtractor())
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => Extractor.ExtractTicketData(ticket.data));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if this is a good way to perform this process as I'm relatively new to developing APIs and I'm concerned about performance and scalability.

EDIT: After reading the post provided by Johnathan looks like this is the correct way to aproach it

```cs
public ActionResult<object> GetTicketData([FromBody] PostTicketRequest ticket)
{
    try
    {
        using (var Extractor = new TicketExtractor())
        {
            return Extractor.ExtractTicketData(ticket.data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to use `Task.Run` in an API. If the method is inherently synchronous, expose it as such, and allow the caller to offload the operation to the threadpool if that is what they want to do.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: Thank you @JohnathanBarclay for your quick response, this post is indeed very helpfull!

Comment: This is also relevant: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: Thanks!! @TheodorZoulias I will give it a read too